# interpreting alpha variable in scipy interval function

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, confidence-interval

I am using scipy's interval function for a normal random variable to calculate the confidence interval. However, there seems be some misunderstanding about the significance level.

From scipy.stats.norm docs:
***Signature: stats.norm.interval(alpha, *args, **kwds)**
Docstring:
Confidence interval with equal areas around the median.*

Parameters:
alpha : array_like of float
    Probability that an rv will be drawn from the returned range.
    Each value should be in the range [0, 1].

It seems that they are representing the alpha parameter to be the confidence level rather than the significance level. For example, in statistics an alpha value of 0.05 would mean 5% significance level and 95% confidence level. However, scipy expect to pass 0.95 for alpha variable's value. This is confusing as it should be 0.05 going by statistics terminology. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything.  If you ignore the *name* of the first argument, the function does what it says in the docstring; the docstring never calls the first argument a signifcance level.  The name `alpha` appears to be an unfortunate choice for that argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the quantity called `alpha` in `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval` would be called `1-alpha` in statistics textbooks. You are not missing anything.  It's just a suboptimal name choice.

The only discussion of the name of that parameter that I found concerned [a different name collision](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5982):

> Sigh.
>   Given that both `interval` and `levy_stable` are quite esoteric,[...]